# Object Oriented approach to rooms and dungeons in an rpg

Tags: python, class

As part of a project for school I have to write a program that involves the use of classes and a GUI, and because I did a similar, non-Object oriented version last year; I'm re-creating a text based rpg using tkinter for the GUI aspect.

My problem arises when designing the rooms and the dungeon, and how they all fit together. My last one was overly basic and followed as shown:

```
    if currentRoom == 1:
        print('<Room description>')
        print('1] <Option one>')
        print('2] <Option two>')
        etc...

        userinput = int(input('>>_:'))

        if userinput = 1:
            # Do stuff
```

Where the player's location in the world was represented by a single number that corresponded to a room number on an old D&D map. Options were room specific and re-written for each room, the program kept looping around until it was told to stop (when 'while running' was false).

The command input is handled by an App class; when the user presses enter it checks the contents of a tkinter entry widget and filters it, looking for predefined phases (go, talk, equip, etc...).

While output is written to a temporary file which is then read from and displayed via a label widget.

I was wondering how you would do this when the room was an object, and how you would you know which rooms lead to each-other, and what direction you would have to travel in to get there (ie: 'go north').

Comment: Please do not use tags on questions if you are not familiar with their meaning on *this* site. Each tag has a "tag wiki" page defining it. The FAQ for this site mentions professional programmers, then "enthusiasts". RPG is a programming language, introduced by IBM, and is used primarily by professional programmers for decades to create the business applications that a large percentage of companies depend upon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine every room would consist of a list of things it contained. At the start of the game, you would create a list of rooms, each containing their respective monsters, items, and pathways to other rooms.

```
class Room:
    def __init__(self,description,items,monsters,paths):
        self.description=description
        self.items=items
        self.monsters=monsters
        self.paths=paths
    def interact(self):
        #player interactions here, return number of room player travels to
        pass

list_of_rooms=[
    Room("An easy room with no monsters",["Potion"],[],[1])
    Room("A hard room with some lemons",["Lemon","Lemon"],["Monster"],[0])]

current_room=0
game_over=False
while not game_over:
    current_room=list_of_rooms[current_room].interact()
```

However, this will create a more structured game than the example you gave, which had the possibility to be very rule-less. This object-oriented approach is more suited to a game which has set rules.

I also suggest creating a classed for NPC interactions (notably the dialogue paths), items, monsters, and so forth.

Comment: But how would you know what room a path would lead to? And your example looks like what I've been looking for.

Comment: Every room is assigned a number (it's index in the `list_of_rooms`). In the example I've given, a path is simply a number corresponding to a index in the `list_of_rooms` (and thus a room).